# Django, cannot import name ~~ Error, but i cant find why it is

Tags: django

**app1 : title //
title.models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from relationship.models import ContentRelationship
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Title(models.Model):
    titleText = models.TextField(max_length=160, unique=True)
    titleRelationship = models.OneToOneField('relationship.ContentRelationship', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titleText
```

**app2 : relationship //
relationship.models.py**

```
from title.models import Title

class ContentRelationship(models.Model):
    allow_set = models.ManyToManyField('UserRelationship', related_name="wdt_set", symmetrical=False, through="Wdt", blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

@receiver(post_save, sender=Title)
def create_contentrelationship(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ContentRelationship.objects.create(Title=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Title)
def save_contentrelationship(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.contentrelationship.save()
```

**What i want is that if i create Title instance, then ContentRelationship also be created.**

But on that code, there is

`File "C:/Dev/TestProject/Test1\title\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from relationship.models import ContentRelationship
ImportError: cannot import name 'ContentRelationship'`

I searched and carefully made `ForeignKey or ManyToManyField`'s to argument be `'relationship.ContentRelationship'`. In other words, I made it string.

But it didn't work.

**Edit**
My Project Structure :

[image]

Part that i erased has poor names. So i erased it. sorry.

Comment: Could you post your project structure?

Comment: @nik_m I edited, nik_m

Comment: Try removing this import `from relationship.models import ContentRelationship` since you do not need it. You're using the string `'relationship.ContentRelationship'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing this import:

```
from relationship.models import ContentRelationship
```

since you do not need it. You're using the string

```
'relationship.ContentRelationship'
```